# Cannot install i-nex on ubuntu 20.04

Tags: gui, hardware, system

I can't install i-nex on ubuntu 20.04 using the command line:
sudo add-apt-repository ppa: nemh / gambas3

Please. help me!

Comment: Did you use whitespaces in PPA name? Did command execute successfully?

Answer (score 0):

the command you used

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa: nemh / gambas3
```

only adds a repo. To install you will still need to update and actually install:

```
sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install <pakage>
```

Answer (score 0):

Error: need a repository as argument

correct lines:

sudo add-apt-repository ppa:nemh/gambas3

sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install i-nex

but:

Error: no pakage found

Comment: There is not any i-nex package for 20.04 in the ppa:nemh/gambas3 repository.